# recieving an error 'undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.navigation' while trying to navigate to another screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

returning this error while tying to navigate using switchnavigation.

i have tried removing this. props then returns undefined 'navigation'.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer , withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import layout from '../../constants/LayoutStyle'
import QuoteScreen from './QuoteScreen';

 const HomeScreen = () => {

 return (
           <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
           <View style={{position: 'absolute',top: hp('50%')+wp('37.5%'),left:wp('15%'),width: wp('32.5%'),height: 
      wp('32.5%'),backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'}}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',flex:1}}>
            <Icon name="ios-book" color="purple" size={wp('10%')}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quote')}
              />
            <Text style={styles.tabTextStyle}>Books</Text>
            </View>
  </View>

    );
 };

 const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
     Home: HomeScreen,
     Quote: QuoteScreen,
   }
 );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class app extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />
    }
  }
```

expected to complete navigation properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HomeScreen** is a functional component and hence you should not use this.props.navigation, just say props.navigation.

And If you want to use props inside the function component, then use should pass props as an argument to that functional component. Like this =>

```
 const HomeScreen = (props) => {
    return (
       <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
       <View style={{position: 'absolute',top: 
          hp('50%')+wp('37.5%'),left:wp('15%'),width: wp('32.5%'),height: 
  wp('32.5%'),backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'}}>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',flex:1}}>
        <Icon name="ios-book" color="purple" size={wp('10%')}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quote')}
          />
        <Text style={styles.tabTextStyle}>Books</Text>
        </View>
   </View>
   );
};
```

If this does not work then pass navigation as props to **HomeScreen** component wherever u use, Like this =>

```
<HomeScreen 
  navigation = {this.props.navigation} // or navigation = {props.navigation}, if it is functional component
/>
```

Comment: the 1 st solution solved my issue. thanks for the help anand

Comment: Hi Vishnu, I would like to suggest one thing, please use navigation functions in class-based component only  rather than functional components

Comment: Should i chane it to a claas based component?

Comment: Either U Change This Component to class-based component, or handle this navigation in the [arent Component of the home screen using the props.
I also suggest you to use less class-based component wherever state management, api call re render method is required.